# Driver working issue

Tags: windows, driver

my Battery driver is working on 64 bit , but is not working on 32 bit. Platform is windows.

I am not able to come to any conclusion. What could be the possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

If the driver is available for windows x64, normaly it must be available for x86 also. So you should search for the driver. Most of the drivers can be installed by windows update without installing manually a driver, so start search the update. Also i think you dont need a driver for the battery or is there a special reason for? The laptop battery drivers / softwares often only install a power plan which also can be configured manually if you dont want to use the microsoft standard plans. greats

Comment: The driver for battery management is written by me only. It is working on 64 bit, not on 32 bit. Thats what i am in doubt that what could be the scenario. Any generic concept ?

Comment: can you discripe what the driver does - the functions ? in which language is he written ? is it an application (exe) to install or is it only a driver (inf)? what does not work with the driver on windows x86 ? only a massage that the driver is for windows x64 ?  if you dont give informations, how we can help you ? ..